# Как сделать плавную навигацию которая будет подсвечивать место на котором находится пользователь?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такая плавная навигация по странице. Как сделать чтобы в навигационном меню добавлялся класс "current" в зависимости от места на котором сейчас находится пользователь? Чтобы когда человек постепенно крутил мышку, ему отображался раздел сайта в навигационном меню.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let target  = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
    });
  });

});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0 4em;
    margin: 0;
    font: 14px/1.8 Helvetica;
    color: #444;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* = Стили для контента */
#main {
    width: 75%;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    position: relative;
}

p {
  height: 100vh;
}

/* = Стили для ссылки наверх */
h2 a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #444;
    display: block;
}

/* = Стили для содержания */
aside {
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 78%;
    top: 50%;
}
li {
    list-style: square;
    color: #006600;
}
li a {
    font: bold italic 16px Helvetica;
    color: #006600;
}
li a:hover {
    color: #990000;
}

.current {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <h2 id="one">One</h2>
    <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h2 id="two">Two</h2>
    <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <h2 id="three">Three</h2>
    <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h2 id="four">Four</h2>
    <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h2 id="five">Five</h2>
    <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h2 id="six">Six</h2>
    <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>

<aside>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="current" href="#one">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#five">Five</a></li>
        <li><a href="#six">Six</a></li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0 4em;
            margin: 0;
            font: 14px/1.8 Helvetica;
            color: #444;
        }
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        /* = Стили для контента */
        #main {
            width: 75%;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 1.8em;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
            position: relative;
        }

        p {
            height: 100vh;
        }

        /* = Стили для ссылки наверх */
        h2 a {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            padding: 0 10px;
            font-size: 11px;
            color: #fff;
            background: #444;
            display: block;
        }

        /* = Стили для содержания */
        aside {
            display: block;
            width: 20%;
            position: fixed;
            left: 78%;
            top: 50%;
        }
        li {
            list-style: square;
            color: #006600;
        }
        li a {
            font: bold italic 16px Helvetica;
            color: #006600;
        }
        li a:hover {
            color: #990000;
        }

        .current {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600,800,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.10.0/lodash.js"></script>
    <div id="main">
        <h2 id="one">One</h2>
        <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <h2 id="two">Two</h2>
        <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <h2 id="three">Three</h2>
        <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <h2 id="four">Four</h2>
        <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <h2 id="five">Five</h2>
        <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <h2 id="six">Six</h2>
        <p>Тут текст Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <aside>
        <ul>
            <li><a id="one" href="#one" class="current">One</a></li>
            <li><a id="two" href="#two">Two</a></li>
            <li><a id="three" href="#three">Three</a></li>
            <li><a id="four" href="#four">Four</a></li>
            <li><a id="five" href="#five">Five</a></li>
            <li><a id="six" href="#six">Six</a></li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                let target  = this.hash, $target = $(target);

                $('html, body').stop().animate({ 'scrollTop': $target.offset().top }, 900, 'swing', function () {
                    window.location.hash = target;
                });
            });
            // устанавливает класс current активной странице 
            function setActiveClass (id) {
                $( "a" ).each(function( index ) {
                    $( this ).removeClass( "current" )
                });
                $( `a#${id}` ).addClass( "current" )
            }
            // получение позиций "страниц"
            function getSectionCurrentPositions () {
                const sectionsIds = [ 'one', 'two', "three", "four", "five", "six" ];
                return sectionsIds.map(id => {
                    const offset = $(`#${id}`).offset().top;
                    return {
                        id: id,
                        offset: parseInt(offset) 
                    };
                })
            }
            const positionsOffset = getSectionCurrentPositions();
            // обработчик события скрола на странице
            // механику можете прописать свою
            function scrollHandler () {
                const scrollOffset = $(document).scrollTop();
                
                let currentPageId = positionsOffset[0].id;
                if(scrollOffset <= positionsOffset[0].offset) {
                    currentPageId = positionsOffset[0].id;
                } else if(scrollOffset >= positionsOffset[positionsOffset.length - 1].offset) {
                    currentPageId = positionsOffset[positionsOffset.length - 1].id;
                } else {
                    let currentPage = positionsOffset.find((el, index, array) => {
                        return el.offset <= scrollOffset && scrollOffset < array[index + 1].offset;
                    });
                    currentPageId = currentPage.id;
                }
                console.log('currentPageId', currentPageId);
                setActiveClass(currentPageId);
            }
            // debounce чтобы не дергать функцию при каждом собитии скрола
            $(document).on("scroll", _.debounce(scrollHandler, 250));
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```